# how to Validate Multiple TextBoxes , combo box and datetime picker infragistics

Tags: validation, combobox, textbox, datetimepicker

We have a code to validate all textbox below:

For Each ctl As **Control** In Controls

If TypeOf ctl Is Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraTextEditor AndAlso ctl.Text = "" Then
ctl.Focus()
MsgBox(ctl.Name)
End If
Next

Here we need to get all infragistics controls.

Or else suggest us to validate all the infragistics controls such as textbox, date time picker, combo.

Comment: anyone there?
kindly help me as soon as possible please.

Comment: Please anyone atleast reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got links how to validate numerous infragistics controls

https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/winvalidator

https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/winvalidator-validate-a-group-of-controls

https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/winvalidator-validate-all-controls-associated-with-winvalidator

https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/winvalidator-determine-if-a-value-is-in-a-specified-list

https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/winvalidator-validate-during-a-specific-event